# Redirect to settings page after install

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I can't find any info on this anywhere but i'm sure iv'e seen it done before.

I would like to have a user taken to the settings page for my plugin after install, so either auto-redirected or change the "back to plugins" link to a custom link.

Thanks in advance

**SOLVED**

```
function myplugin_activate() {    
    // TODO: Install your plugin here.

    // I don't know of any other redirect function, so this'll have to do.
    wp_redirect(admin_url('options-general.php?page=myplugin_settings'));exit;
    // You could use a header(sprintf('Location: %s', admin_url(...)); here instead too.
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'myplugin_activate');
```

@Zack - Your method works great however you forgot to exit after wp_redirect. (source http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Register an activation hook and then redirect the user's browser when you're done installing your plugin.

```
function myplugin_activate() {    
    // TODO: Install your plugin here.

    // I don't know of any other redirect function, so this'll have to do.
    wp_redirect(admin_url('options-general.php?page=myplugin_settings'));
    // You could use a header(sprintf('Location: %s', admin_url(...)); here instead too.
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'myplugin_activate');
```

Comment: Note that "options-general.php?page=myplugin_settings" should reflect your options page request uri.

Comment: works perfect however we need to exit; after wp_redirect. See my edit.

Answer (score 4):

I see the question is already answered. But there is a alternate scenario where you might  want to redirect to settings page after a **theme installed**. You can do it very easily using following codes :)

```
if (is_admin() && isset($_GET['activated'])){

    wp_redirect(admin_url("themes.php?page=ot-theme-options"));
}
```

You just have to replace the following code `themes.php?page=ot-theme-options` 
With your own setting page url.

It is farly easy to do and we are using WP redirect function.

Thanks 
Sabbir

Answer (score 3):

Well, you also can use another and more elegant solution:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, function () {
    add_option('your_plugin_do_activation_redirect', true);
});

add_action('admin_init', function () {
    if (get_option('your_plugin_do_activation_redirect', false)) {
        delete_option('your_plugin_do_activation_redirect');
        if(wp_safe_redirect("options-general.php?page=myplugin_settings")) exit();
    }
});
```

Approved answer is old and produce error inside activation or redirect you to 404 page inside admin. This solution provide you safe redirection with no errors.

Comment: The awesome solution should be upvoted. Thanks @Ivijan Stefan Stipić

Comment: This solution works properly.